# Very large tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I have a very large `breakable` `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
\blindtext[150]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

that exceeds the maximal dimension and causes the following error.

```
! Dimension too large.
<argument> \ht \tcb@upperbox 
                             +\dp \tcb@upperbox 
l.11 \end{tcolorbox}
```

When I use the `batchmode` as suggested for a [very large `mdframed` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131350/long-frames-in-mdframed) I get a document with a single page and a colorbox that does not surround the content. The `tcolorbox` documentation states the following

```
The box content is a TEX \vbox register which has a restricted capacity`.
Therefore, you cannot place hundreds of pages inside a tcolorbox.
```

What is the appropriate way of dealing with very large color boxes?

**Edit**

To add some context as there might as well be a better solution for my problem, I have a large list of small paragraphs (probably one or two lines). I don't know statically how many there are or how long a single paragraph is. I would like to put these paragraphs one after the other on a page as long as they fit and make a page break otherwise. The content of each page should be surrounded by a box. In fact, I additionally would like to separate each pair of consecutive paragraphs by a separator as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186709/remove-segmentation-at-page-breaks). I also looked for multi page tabular environments but did not find a fit either.

Comment: We probably need some more context here: at first glance I don't see that this really wants to be in a box at all, given the size. What's the real use case?

Comment: I think it's a good question because I would like to have a solution myself (for larger listings, e.g.). The answer of David Carlisle to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131350/long-frames-in-mdframed seems to be promising. Currently, I don't have the time too persue it, but I will do later. The core of the question is, if it is possible to do a \vsplit from a \vbox which is itself higher than the maximal dimension.

Comment: You can `\vsplit` a `\vbox` which is longer than `\maxdimen` as long as you don't try to access its dimension as the result is unpredictable: if I try with `\setbox0=\vbox{\blindtext[2000]}\showthe\ht0`, TeX reports `-22137.05556pt`; but it's happy to `\vsplit` it.

Comment: @egreg Do you know if there is any reliable test code that will give me: yes, the \vbox is longer than \maxdimen ?

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm I'm afraid there isn't. `:(`

Comment: I made some test code and asked a new question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187854/measure-a-very-large-vbox. If I could get rid of the annoying messages, this could be base to enlarge the largest possible `tcolorbox` by factor 4.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It took some time and help from others, namely egreg and Heiko Oberdiek, to find a suitable solution, but now I have one.

I made a new enhanced version of `tcolorbox` which is at the time of writing `3.10pre1 (2014/07/16)`. It's a pre-version available at [GitHub](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox), but it will be compatible to an official CTAN version to appear later.

With this new version, the normal breakable `tcolorbox` content length is extended from about 16384pt **by factor 4** to about 65536pt. If needed, this maximum can be extended by an option key as far as compiler memory allows.

As a consequence, your example compiles without any problem. Without any further tweaks, also the following compiles:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext,pgffor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
\foreach \n in {1,...,455}
  {\textbf{\color{red}(\n)} \blindtext[1]\par}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

> This compiles to a document with **125 pages**.

This number of pages is depending on actual the size of a single-page `tcolorbox`. But it should be save for other cases with say up to 100 pages of boxed content.

This limit can be overcome using the new option `breakable=unlimited` which uses another algorithm. This algorithm is not perfect but could influence a single interline space every 65536pt (I would say: that's not too bad...).
Since a breakable `tcolorbox` is a `\box` which is completely processed in memory, the compiler memory is the next limit. Using `pdflatex` with MiKTeX, the following example compiles without tweaks on my system:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext,pgffor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable=unlimited]
\foreach \n in {1,...,1300}
  {\textbf{\color{red}(\n)} \blindtext[1]\par}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

> This compiles to a document with **355 pages**.

Again, the number of pages depends on the geometry and also on the content of the boxes.

If that's not enough, the compiler memory could be increased. I took the heavy hammer (MiKTeX dependend) I use for monstrous documents, i.e.

> pdflatex --pool-size=10000000 --max-strings=500000 --save-size=50000 --extra-mem-bot=4000000 --extra-mem-top=4000000 jobname.tex

With that hammer, the following code compiles on my system:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext,pgffor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable=unlimited]
\foreach \n in {1,...,5000}
  {\textbf{\color{red}(\n)} \blindtext[1]\par}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

> This compiles to a document with **1364 pages**.

Comment: @JanChristiansen You're welcome :-) I guess your question was/is interesting for many people (including me).