# mdframed minted on several pages: LaTeX long to respond and 100% CPU

Tags: mdframed, minted

I try to insert some Python code in a LaTeX document using an `mdframed` `minted` but it take really really ... really long to compile (so long I must abort, CPU goes to 100% all the time).

In the stdout, I got thousands of thousands of lines:

```
Overfull \vbox (2655.50832pt too high) detected at line 3665
Overfull \vbox (2656.50832pt too high) detected at line 3665
```

Here's how I tried based on [minted truncates the code if it doesn't fit into one page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23663/minted-truncates-the-code-if-it-doesnt-fit-into-one-page) :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british,UKenglish,USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
(...)
% pretend to already have loaded float
\makeatletter 
\@namedef{ver@float.sty}{3000/12/31}
\makeatother
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{mdframed}
%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=black, topline=true, bottomline=true,
  leftline=false, rightline=false, backgroundcolor=yellow!20!white]
\begin{minted}[
frame=lines,
framesep=2mm,
baselinestretch=1.0,
bgcolor=lightgray,
fontsize=\footnotesize,
linenos
]
{python}

reaaaaally long code with hundreds of line here (it must end up on multiple pages)

\end{minted}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

With small snippets of code it works like a charm.

I also tried:

```
\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=white, topline=false, bottomline=false,
  leftline=false, rightline=false]
\inputminted[
frame=lines,
framesep=2mm,
baselinestretch=1.0,
bgcolor=lightgray,
fontsize=\footnotesize,
linenos
]
{python}
{/path/to/script.py}

\end{minted}
\end{mdframed}
```

I got the same behaviour.

#### Update:

Here's a useful (?) extract of the log file:

```
(...)

Package mdframed Info: Not enough space on this page on input line 89.

Overfull \vbox (170.2141pt too high) detected at line 89
 [] 

Package mdframed Info: Box was splittet wrong
 starting loop to iterate the splitting point
(mdframed)              on input line 89.

Overfull \vbox (171.2141pt too high) detected at line 89
 []

Overfull \vbox (172.2141pt too high) detected at line 89
 []

Overfull \vbox (173.2141pt too high) detected at line 89
 []

(...)
```

Comment: With a fake long Python script I get `! Dimension too large.` Probably `tcolorbox` is better instead of `mdframed`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Anyway, `tcolorbox` doesn't seem to split the code on several pages. It's just like printing only the `minted` block without embedding it into "something else" like an `mdframed` or `tcolorbox`.

Comment: You probably have to tell the box (`mdframed` or `tcolorbox`) that the box is allowed to break. I think it is the default in `mdframed`, but not i `tcolorbox`.

Comment: I found the `breakable` option here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187741/very-large-tcolorbox which doesn't seem to be recognized by my side :
`! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/breakable', to which you passed 'unlimited', and I'm going to ignore it.`

Comment: Maybe, you forgot to set the `breakable` package option? I added an answer which works for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mdframed` and `tcolorbox` should be able to be applied quite the same. But, if your content is **really long**, using `breakable=unlimited` for `tcolorbox` may solve your problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british,UKenglish,USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%(...)
\usepackage[skins,minted,breakable]{tcolorbox}
%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{
  enhanced,
  listing only,
  minted options={
    %frame=lines,
    %framesep=2mm,
    baselinestretch=1.0,
    %bgcolor=lightgray,
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    linenos,
    breaklines,
  },
  minted language=python,
  colback=yellow!20!white,
  boxrule=0pt,
  boxsep=0pt,
  frame hidden,
  borderline horizontal={0.4pt}{0pt}{black},
  breakable=unlimited,
}

reaaaaally long code with hundreds of line here (it must end up on multiple pages)

\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

Just to explain what happens:

- `mdframed` and `tcolorbox` both use basic TeX `\vsplit` commands to split a content box. The maximal total height is about 65536pt for the content which should be enough for *usual* content (ca. 90 pages).
- `breakable=unlimited` is an extension which avoids measuring the box height. Here, the compiler memory is the limiting force, but about 300 pages should work (and even more with extended memory).

**Update:**

Alternatively, to input a file, you may use the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british,UKenglish,USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%(...)
\usepackage[skins,minted,breakable]{tcolorbox}
%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\tcbinputlisting{
  listing file=\jobname.tex,% <------- file name
  enhanced,
  listing only,
  minted options={
    %frame=lines,
    %framesep=2mm,
    baselinestretch=1.0,
    %bgcolor=lightgray,
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    linenos,
    breaklines,
  },
  minted language=python,
  colback=yellow!20!white,
  boxrule=0pt,
  boxsep=0pt,
  frame hidden,
  borderline horizontal={0.4pt}{0pt}{black},
  breakable=unlimited,
}        
\end{document}
```

> Note that `bgcolor=lightgray` has to be removed to avoid boxing the
>   `minted` content! If you really need a gray interior, that could be
>   done by `tcolorbox` options, but I think it looks better now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there a way to use an `\inputminted` statement instead rather than copying all the code within the *.tex document? A first try with copy-pasting let me with an empty yellowish box taking the place of a full page only.

Comment: @s.k Yes, with \tcbinputlisting. I updated my answer. Also note that `bgcolor=lightgray` is to be removed to make the content breakable.

Comment: By the way I'm currently relying on the `listings` package instead if `minted` to have some clean output: `\lstinputlisting[columns=fullflexible,caption={script.py},language=Python]`

Comment: @s.k The same thing could be done for `listings` as well with different options (but you asked for `minted`).

Comment: Yes, I asked for `minted` and in between, as it didn't work, I also tried other stuff like `listings` e.g. But your solution seems pretty good now, I'm impressed! Except for a little tiny detail: there is some nice arrows to show line-returns that where added where lines are too long in the script (I know, this shouldn't happen...it's not a clean code yet). It's really nice. Except for some line where it didn't work. These particular lines are lines where there is no blank spaces. I will add some, this is not a problem. I just liked to give this information.

Comment: @s.k When `minted`'s `breaklines` option is used, it will only break lines at spaces. You need to add `breakanywhere`, or specify characters for `breakbefore` or `breakafter`, to control breaking when there are no spaces.

Comment: @s.k Just for clarification: All settings for displaying the code are from the `minted` package. So, please, refer to its documentation for things like `breakanywhere` as @G. Poore wrote. The *decoration* type settings like title, frame, background, etc. are coming from the `tcolorbox` package and are documented there, e.g. `breakable=unlimited`.